# Angular 7 Execute Function Before ngAfterContentInit

Tags: typescript, angular7

i want to write value which i get from http to variable before ngAfterContentInit. But i cannot find any solution.

```
post:any;


constructor{

        this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(
          data => {
            this.post = data;
          });
      }




 ngAfterContentInit{
console.log(this.post); //gives undefined
}
```

How can i execute and compelete http.get function before content init? Console.log works before get data.

Answer (score 0):

Your class must use the OnInit interface. ngOnInit () inside which you want to perform all the operations that must be performed first.

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // your actions here
    }
}
```

Comment: export class Tab2Page implements OnInit { 
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.post = data;
        console.log("get operation done");
      });
      console.log(this.post);
  }
}

In chrome console;
tab2.page.ts:45 undefined
tab2.page.ts:43 get operation done

I did what you said. But again console.log works before this.post = data; command line.